# SWT: remove highlight from tab-title

Tags: tabs, swt

How can I remove the highlight around the currently active tab in a CTabFolder?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you can't do that. You can, however, use a CTabFolder instead of a TabFolder. CTabFolder has some more possibilities to work with, and the highlight doesn't occur in the first place anyway, so, that helps.